# Combining cells to form a formula

Tags: excel-formula

I couldn't find a way to create a formula for my data directly in the formula tab, since I need different values in each row, example:
row 1:  MEAN(A23:A27)
row 2:  MEAN(A29:A33)
So, it's always a "+4" from the first value to the second. 
What I did was to write down every part of the formula in different cells, so I only need to write down the first value:

col 1: MEAN(A

col 2: "value"
col 3:   :

col 4:  A

col 5: =C2+4
col 6:        )
col 7: =C1&C2&C3&C4&C5&C6

then it returns: MEAN(A        23           :            A27        )

So what happens is that col 6 returns me the written formula "MEAN(A23:A27)", and what I want is that this column or another actually gives me the result of the formula, the actual mean between a:23 and a27. 
Anybody knows what should I do? 
ps. I already tried creating another column with the "=" sign and attaching it, but then the formula simply comes with the "=" in front and is not returning the value.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Wrap your concatenation in an `INDIRECT( ... )`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating a formula to turn concatenated text into a range name and dragging this formula across](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945800/creating-a-formula-to-turn-concatenated-text-into-a-range-name-and-dragging-this)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 =mean(INDEX(A:A,C2):INDEX(A:A,C2 + 4))
```